# What can I do to debug random Wi-Fi disconnects?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I'm running Windows 8.1 on a desktop machine, using a WiFi dongle to connect to the local network (an 802.11n network, according to WifiInfoView). The nearest base station is about 20 feet away in the same room, practically with line-of-sight to the dongle.

I have a selection of WiFi dongles (a big one with an antenna, a small one about 1/2" square, and another one that is very tiny), and I have experienced the same problem with all three.

Some time (anywhere from a few minutes to a few hours) after establishing a connection to the network (an unsecured campus wireless network), the WiFi will just disconnect. For example, every day I come in, the WiFi will have disconnected overnight.

The WiFi icon in the taskbar will go from being 5 white bars to 5 gray bars (indicating no signal), with a six-pointed star (not sure what that means) or an exclamation mark (also not sure what that means). When this occurs, I have to open the connection settings, select the network, hit Disconnect, then hit Connect (I usually check "Connect Automatically", but the problem occurs even with this unchecked).

Note that the connection strength with all three adapters is 5 bars, and I've never seen anything but 0 bars or 5 bars (the connection is either strong or dead). The school network is the only active WiFi profile (as determined by `netsh wlan show profiles`).

Pretty much everyone here has a Mac laptop (including me), and the WiFi connections never seem to randomly cut out for the Macs. I have also tested these dongles with a Raspberry Pi, and I don't see these kinds of disconnects there either.

What debugging steps should I take from this point?

Comment: OK, why is this being down voted? I'm new to SU, so I would very much appreciate feedback...

Comment: Can you describe the machine you're running W8.1 on?  Is it the kind of machine that might have a flaky USB port, as @Phil describes below?  Have you tried all the USB ports that machine provides?  If other USB devices are connected and require power, perhaps they are power-cycling as well, or drawing too much power.

Comment: @CharlesLindsay: I will try as many of those as possible when I go in tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in a bit of a spot because you do not have access to the APs the campus uses.

I’d suggest the possibilities are thus:

- Operating system / core driver issue
- wireless access point compatibility issue

I have seen this on multiple Windows 8/8.1 systems, so I wonder if it is OS related—especially since you’ve troubleshooted using multiple dongles. The fastest way to check if that is the case would be to download and use a live OS of some sort to verify if you still have that occur.

If you can borrow a Windows laptop and use one of your dongles and/or check with anybody using a windows unit if they have the same occur, that will quickly answer if its an access point issue.

Something that worked at a client location—we had an access point that simply would not work with a new Windows 8 computer—hanged obvious things such as security mode and frequency, and even more obscure items such as preamble. We had a wireless extender on hand, so we decided to use that to verify the problem. In fact, the Windows 8 system connected flawlessly to the extender, so we left in on location and it’s worked perfectly since. Consider that would be a cheap solution if it is such an incompatibility.

Comment: The school here generally disallows unauthorized wireless equipment (and from what I understand, they periodically sweep to find such equipment, since I've heard of people getting notices to shutdown their wireless routers). So the range extender may not work. The WiFi router is about twenty feet from the machine; I can unplug it and plug it back in (though I probably shouldn't), but otherwise that's the extent of my access to the router.

Answer (score 2):

The reason may be that your PC has noisy, poor quality USB port. You may want to try a powered hub. Also, raspberry Pi can be configured as an extender - you'd need an ethernet cable though. Yet another exotic solution (in case it is an issue with Windows) would be to install Virtual Box on your desktop, set up a Linux VM and let Linux manage the dongle and set the VM as a proxy or a router.